# How to remove/cleanup EventListener when handler is outside useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if I could cleanup the Event Listener if its handler declared outside the useEffect hook, I saw many examples and tutorials removing Event Listeners this way, by implementing the handler function inside the useEffect hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    
    function updateSize(){
      setSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
    updateSize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
  }, []);
```

While I did implement the handler out side the useEffect hook, the listener is working fine, but not sure if it a correct way and would be able to get cleaned by useEffect hook since it is outside the scope.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([0, 0]);

   const updateSize = () => {
     setSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

    updateSize();
    return () => window.remove
  }, []);



  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove/cleanup EventListener when handler is outside useEffect hook?

Even if the *handler* (in your case - `updateSize`) is declared **outside** the `useEffect` hook, you still have the reference to it. Does not really matter if it's declared outside the hook.

Just remove it (clean up) as you would do with a normal listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

   return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
   };
}, []);
```

**Note**: Remember to put it inside the *dependency array* of `useEffect` and wrap the `updateSize` with `useCallback` hook.